# LogPlot with a Rectangle

Tags: plotting, geometry

If I combine a `Plot` with a `Rectangle` (as following) I obtain the expected result:

```
fig = Plot[10^-x, {x, 1, 5}];
rec = Graphics[{LightGray, Rectangle[{2, 10^-2}, {3, 10^-4}]}];
Show[rec, fig, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> .5]
```

[image]

However, If I use `LogPlot` I obtain the following:

```
fig = LogPlot[10^-x, {x, 1, 5}]
rec = Graphics[{LightGray, Rectangle[{2, -2}, {3, -4}]}];
Show[rec, fig, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> .5]
```

[image]

That is, the rectangle is at the correct position but the curve has been shifted. Indeed, `fig` is now:

[image]

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Seems a simple enough mistake - you took the base-10 log of your rectangle coordinates, but `LogPlot` uses the natural log.

Comment: @Jason B. thanks! You are indeed right! Could you please convert this comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation for [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html):

> Show uses the options from the first graphic

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you change the order you will get the scaling options of the [`LogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogPlot.html) instead, including the interpretation of the coordinates

```
fig = LogPlot[10^-x, {x, 1, 5}];
rec = Graphics[{LightGray, Rectangle[{2, -2}, {3, -4}]}];
Show[fig, rec, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> .5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Solution

```
LogPlot[10^-x
 , {x, 1, 5}
 , Prolog -> {LightGray, Rectangle[{2, Log[10^-2]}, {3, Log[10^-3]}]}
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 , AspectRatio -> 1/2
 , PlotRange -> {10^-6, 1}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I see, but how do I obtain the correct plot?

Comment: @Valerio I have updated my answer.

Comment: thanks but I prefer the solution by Jason B. as it uses the original structure; I need indeed to put many objects together.

Answer (score 0):

We can produce your first image with

```
Plot[10^-x, {x, 1, 5}, Frame -> True,
 Prolog -> {LightGray, Rectangle[{2, 10^-2}, {3, 10^-3}]}]
```

I would therefore expect the following to work, and it does.

```
LogPlot[10^-x, {x, 1, 5}, Frame -> True,
 Prolog -> {LightGray, Rectangle[{2, Log[10^-2]}, {3, Log[10^-3]}]}]
```

Note that I changed a 4 to a 3; change it back if that's not what you meant.